# Apex String Query Error

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to compute a query from a string variable such as

```
 public String query = 'SELECT Id,ownerid,closedate,name FROM Opportunity WHERE isClosed =false and closedate =: dtreshold  and (stagename != "Pending Payment" OR stagename != "Complete"  OR stagename !=    "Rejected"   OR stagename !=    "Cancelled"  )';
```

But upon executing it it gives me the following error:

> 10:50:26:019 EXCEPTION_THROWN [17]|System.QueryException: line 1:124 no viable alternative at character '"'

Comment: did you try to use the single quote with backslash at stagename checking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`no viable alternative at character '"'` usually means that you have used double quotes " instead of single quotes '.

To solve this, you should replace your double quotes with single quotes and escape them with a backslash. Try this:

```
 public String query = 'SELECT Id,ownerid,closedate,name FROM Opportunity WHERE isClosed =false and closedate =: dtreshold  and (stagename != \'Pending Payment\' OR stagename != \'Complete\'  OR stagename !=    \'Rejected\'   OR stagename !=    \'Cancelled\'  )';
```